# How to change the default CHARACTER SET and COLLATE for variables/constants?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a user table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `Id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL
  -- more column
);
```

Now when I run the following procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc ()
BEGIN
   SET @searchTerm = '%';
   SELECT * FROM user WHERE FirstName like @searchTerm;
END
```

I get the exception:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,IMPLICIT) and
> (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'    0.000 sec

I have set the character CHARACTER and COLLATE for the entire DB as follow:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Not sure why my variable @searchTerm has `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` for `COLLATE`?

### Update

Originally, when I asked the question, I did not mention that I was running the following script inside the stored procedure:

```
SET @searchTerm = '%';
SELECT * FROM user WHERE FirstName like @searchTerm;
```

I had to update the question, as it turned out that this was the issue.

Comment: to rid you of the need to set collation on variables you would need to change the defualt collation for your database. This isn't trivial are you prepared for a db backup and restore if it belly flops? Otherwise `SET @searchTerm = '%' COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;   
SELECT * FROM user WHERE FirstName LIKE @searchTerm;`

Comment: Thanks... yes, I can backup and restore.

Comment: Specify needed charset/collation in the query: `select * from user where FirstName like @searchTerm COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci ;`. Also specify charset explicitly in the variable assingment: `SET @searchTerm = _utf8mb4'%'`.

Comment: *why my variable @searchTerm has utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci for COLLATE?* See `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'coll%';`, pay attention to the connection collation.

Comment: Did you restart the server after the `ALTER DATABASE` command? or `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` ?

Comment: try 
SET @searchTerm = CONVERT(@searchTerm USING utf8mb4);
before your select query.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell: Thanks for your comment... the script which causing the issue was inside a stored procedure (I had not mentioned this in my question). I had to drop and recreate the stored procedure to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, good lesson...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the collation mismatch between the `FirstName` column and the `@searchTerm` variable is due to MySQL's collation handling rules.

In your query the `FirstName` column is using the `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` collation, but the `@searchTerm` variable is using the `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` collation. When you perform a `LIKE` comparison between these two with different collations, you get the `Illegal mix of collations` error.

You have to ensure that the variable `@searchTerm` uses the same collation as the `FirstName` column.

```
SET @searchTerm = '%';
SET @searchTerm COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci; -- Set the collation explicitly
SELECT * FROM user WHERE FirstName LIKE @searchTerm;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had to drop and recreate the stored procedure after changing the CHARACTER SET and COLLATE, i.e. running the following script:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;
```

Thanks to @Paul Maxwell comment, about restarting the DB, which was a good hint  to find the issue.